# Why can I `curl localhost:<port>` but can't `curl <my IP>:<port>`?

Tags: macos, curl, networking, netcat

I start by retrieving my IP address by running `ifconfig | grep -B7 "status: active"`. Then, I listen on port `12345` by running `nc -l 12345`.

Observations:

- `curl localhost:12345` works
- `curl <my IP>:12345` does not work for me (it times out)
- `curl <my IP>:12345` works for someone who's on the same network as me
- I see traffic when running `sudo tcpdump -i any -nn -v tcp port 12345`, even with the `curl` command that doesn't work for me

Comment: Routing issue? Firewall? Perhaps the IP address is only visible to the outside?

Comment: Turned out a VPN client (FortiClient, specifically) was causing the issue even though I didn't have an active VPN connection. Quitting out of FortiClient didn't resolve the issue. But, somehow, removing FortiClient as a login item on my Mac (and then restarting) resolved the issue. Any idea what might have been going on?

Comment: Just a guess: When you had FortiClient installed, were you able to get to public websites even without the VPN tunnel being up? Some corporate IT departments set up their VPN clients to be "full tunnel", which means all traffic from the host must go via the VPN tunnel, so you can't reach the public Internet without the VPN tunnel being up (or immediately coming up on demand). I could imagine a full tunnel VPN solution not being smart about local IP addresses (other than 127.0.0.0/8 loopback addresses), and thus blocking access to it when the tunnel is down.

Comment: Another possibility is that your home LAN uses a private IP subnet that your IT department also uses internally on the corporate network, so your corporate VPN configuration tries to own the route to that subnet, instead of letting you use it locally.